# Which order multiplet of a given $SU(N)$ is real or complex?

Tags: field-theory, group-theory, representation-theory, symmetry-breaking, complex-numbers

I am studying the $SU(2)$ symmetric Lagrangian in particle physics.

$${\mathcal{L}} = (\partial_\mu \Phi)^\dagger (\partial^\mu \Phi) - (\mu^2 \Phi^ \dagger \Phi + \lambda (\Phi^ \dagger \Phi)^2).$$

In this the $SU(2)$ triplet taken consists of 3 real fields.

$$\Phi = \begin{bmatrix} \phi_1 \\ \phi_2 \\ \phi_3 \end{bmatrix}.$$

I am bit confused about why this triplet needs to be real? Can't it be also complex? Instead of a triplet can we take a doublet? If so, will it be real or complex?

In general if we are given a $SU(N)$ symmetric Lagrangian, is there any convention to choose real multiplet and which order multiplet should we choose so that it is a real multiplet?

Comment: Reality properties should be in the appendix of https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.10969

Comment: The classic look-up for these questions is Slansky: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0370157381900922 
(scanned typewriter version here: https://cds.cern.ch/record/134739/files/198109187.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an incomplete list to start with:

- The fundamental/defining/spinor representation ${\bf 2}$ of $SU(2)$ is a [quaternionic/pseudoreal representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternionic_representation).
- More generally the ${\bf 2j\!+\!1}$ irreducible representation of $SU(2)$ is (pseudo)[real](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_representation) if the spin $j$ is a (half)integer, respectively.
- The fundamental/defining representation ${\bf N}$ of $SU(N)$ for $N>2$ is a [complex representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_representation).